# Check If a User liked

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-oauth

I have an app that works outside of the Facebook. I need the user to like 2 different Facebook pages before go through.

I already have a function to know if the user clicked (and of course liked) those to pages. The problem is if the user already liked the pages. So if the user didn't liked. When he click the 2 likes buttons I will know.

I will add for example in database a liked_both=1 and from that point I will always make the client skip that step. This is not a good practice because if the user remove the like he will skip it since my verification its in database.

This the code I use:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '1426818840916389',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
           //Some ajax function.
        });

    });
```

I can work this to know if the user clicked. But how to know if they already clicked without asking for permissions.

Also I don't have time to ask for a Review Submission (is it really necessary?).

Also I tried this:

```
FB.login(function(response) {

    if (response) {
            console.log(response);
          var user_id = '100000246250649';

          var page_id = "40796308305"; //coca cola
          var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+" and uid="+user_id;

          var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);

          the_query.wait(function(rows) {

              if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                   alert(' LIKE');
                  //here you could also do some ajax and get the content for a "liker" instead of simply showing a hidden div in the page.

              } else {
                 alert('DO NOT LIKE');//and here you could get the content for a non liker in ajax...
              }
          });


      } else {

        // user is not logged in
      }
```

The 'response' I get its only :

> Object {authResponse: Object, status: "connected"}

And even if I define the UID and PAGE_ID the query just wont run I get no errors no response at all.

Maybe I have no options and as far as I searched it's nearly impossible but maybe some bright mind will be able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the graph API to query for all the pages the user has liked:

```
FB.api("/me/likes",function (response) {});
```

Note that to do this you will need to ask for the user_likes permission.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/likes
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0

Comment: I've read it twice now. It seems like you want to check if a user has already liked a page. Is this not the case?

Comment: Yes it is but (Not using user_permissions) I need to launch the campaign and i dont have time to ask for a Review of the APP. So I know how to ask user likes using extended permissions the thing is I dont want to use that if I need to ask for a review (Wich I need as far as I know). For example can I do this using FQL ? My question It's more like... What you want its impossible. Or its not.

Comment: FQL is just a different interface to access the same information. The data it returns also depends on the permissions you have been granted. So if you don't have user_likes you won't be able see user likes in FQL either. The only exception is to detect if the user likes the app page that is associated with your app.

Comment: Thank you man ;) That was exactly what I thought but I wanted to be sure. Cause my Boss says its possible.
Cheers and thank you again ;)